# Connect from Jira Plugin to SQL Server DB using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, plugins, jira

I'm currently stuck with the following problem. I read a lot, I tried a lot but so far I still could not figure out how to solve it.
I would like to achieve the following:

Jira issue tab panel plugin that
connects via JDBC to a SQL Server instance and
retrieves data from a table which
is then displayed in the plugin

Further potentially useful information:

- JIRA Build: 7.13.0
- Application Server: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35 - Servlet API 3.1
- Java Version: 1.8.0_212 - AdoptOpenJDK
- atlassian-plugin-sdk: 8.0.7
- apache-maven: 3.5.4
- amps-dispatcher-maven-plugin: 8.0.0

The issue tab panel plugin itself already worked and I managed to display some basic data (issue and user-data) but no data from SQL was retrieved. The error message in the log was the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://servername\LOCAL;databaseName=dbname;user=user;password=password;
```

In the Jira plugin project I then I added the following dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.aad</groupId>
  <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I ran atlas-clean and afterwards atlas-debug again.

The error message I got was (with 7.0.0.jre8):

```
Cannot start plugin: com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin [171]: 
Unable to resolve 171.0: missing requirement [171.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.microsoft.azure)
```

I partly rebuild the code of the plugin in a maven project in Eclipse and everything works fine. I am able to retrieve the data.
In Eclipse I use driver: mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar which is under referenced libraries. The the java code itself works.

I also tried the following (without success obviously):

- Different sql-server jdbc driver versions (jre8 versions & jre11)
- I also tried to add this mssql.jar the following folders:
- \myPlugin\target\container\tomcat8x\apache-tomcat-8.5.35\lib
- \myPlugin\target\jira\webapp\WEB-INF\lib

I read that I need to add datasources in different xml-files (e.g. dbconfig) but I am confused where exactly I now need to add which code.

If anybody has some suggestions what I could still try, I would be very happy.

For completeness:

See below the class that I use to connect to SQL. This works in Eclipse. Inputs are the conncetion-string (see above) and a simple SQL-query.

```java
public static ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> getRows(String conn, String query) throws SQLException 
{ 
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conn); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rset.getMetaData();
int columncount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> queryResult = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

while (rset.next()) {
Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for (int i = 1; i <= columncount; i++) {
row.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rset.getObject(i));
}
queryResult.add(row);

}
con.close();
return queryResult;

}
// Handle any errors that may have occurred.
catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return queryResult; 
}

}
```

Comment: Which Java version is your Jenkins running on? You are using the Java 11 version of the driver, but if Jenkins is running on Java 8 this won't work.

Comment: As I'm running Jira locally with atlas-debug I don't think Jenkins is used. Tomcat version is apache-tomcat-8.5.35. And from the POM.xml: Jira version is 7.13.0, amps version 8.0.0, maven.compiler.source/target 1.8.

Comment: Maybe you should try the Java 8 version of the mssql-jdbc driver.

Comment: I added the following dependencies in the pom.xml:

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>7.2.2.jre11</version>  
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.aad</groupId>
   <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

Now there is the following error in the log:

Comment: Failed to collect dependencies at com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:7.2.2.jre11: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:7.2.2.jre11: Could not transfer artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:pom:7.2.2.jre11 from/to atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public): Connect to maven.atlassian.com:443 [maven.atlassian.com/18.136.214.23, maven.atlassian.com/18.136.214.21, maven.atlassian.com/18.136.214.22] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: I also tried Microsoft JDBC Driver For SQL Server 7.2.2.jre8.
With this version I get the following error:
com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin-tests: Unable to process plugin to generate OSGi manifest